# XMLHttpRequest responseText is missing characters

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cgi

I seem to be running into an issue where my onreadystatechange function is being called with only part of the string that is being written by my cgi script.    I'm guessing the onreadystatechange is being invoked before the cgi script has finished writing its output, and I'm wondering if there's a way around that...   I have the following

```
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {  
            debug("Got queryGraph response : " + xhttp.responseText);
            debug("parsing json...");
            var rtGd = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            // normal handler here...
          };
      xhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.1.134/cgi-bin/web.cgi?queryGraph_"+timeStart+"_"+timeEnd, true);
      xhttp.send();
```

I'm getting the following debug:

```
Got queryGraph response : {"len":480, "msgIdx":4, "graphData":{
"Data1":[ {"t":1454247107,"v":20.19}, {"t":1454247109,"v":20.19}, 
{"t":1454247111,"v":20.19}, {"t":1454247113,"v":20.19}, 
{"t":1454247115,"v":20.19}, {"t":1454247117,"v":20.19}, 
{"t":1454247119,"v":20.19}, {"t":1454247121,"v":20.19} ], "Data2":[ 
{"t":1454247107,"v":19.94}, {"t":1454247109,"v":19.94}, 
{"t":1454247111,"v":19.94}, {"t":1454247113,"v":19.94}, 
{"t":1454247115,"v":19.94}, {"t":1454247117,"v":19.94}, 
{"t":1454247119,"v":19.94}, {"t":145424712
parsing json...
```

The cgi script prints out the data, followed by `XXX` (for debug purposes), but the end of the data, and the `XXX` does not appear...

```
    printf("\"len\":%d, \"msgIdx\":%d, ", strlen(rspData.json), msgIdx++);
    printf("\"graphData\":%s, ", rspData.json);
    printf("\"XXX\": %d, ", strlen(rspData.json));
```

Comment: You should delay your processing until the `readyState` has a value of `4`, so it is finished. `onreadystatechange` will be called multiple times in the process, before the request actually has finished.

Comment: Thanks.   As you can tell I'm kind of new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `readystate` check in the onreadystatechange callback. A readystate of 4 means "done" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    debug("Got queryGraph response : " + xhttp.responseText);
    debug("parsing json...");
    var rtGd = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    // normal handler here...
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.1.134/cgi-bin/web.cgi?queryGraph_"+timeStart+"_"+timeEnd, true);
xhttp.send();
```